# C Program Compile Error (with header file)

Tags: c, gcc, pic

Here is my code of Header File.

Header File name **16f877a.h**

its code get [from this link](http://www.ecse.rpi.edu/courses/CStudio/SDCC%20Compiler/sdcc-src-2.8.0/sdcc-src-2.8.0/sdcc/device/include/pic/pic16f877a.h)

My File name **led.c**

```
#include "16f877a.h" //IC selection
#fuses XT, NOWDT, NOPROTECT, NOLVP
#use delay (clock =20000000) //clock 20MHz
void main(){
    while(1){
        output_B(0xff); //hex to binary output on port B
        delay_us(500); // delay = 500 x clock period.
        output_B(0x00);
        delay_us(500);
    }
}
```

those files are located in **same folder**

> /home/company/Documents/CCPP/PIC/LedProject

I use **UBUNTU 12.04**.
with **gcc** I compiled a simple hello world program and its runs correctly.
here is my command history in terminal

```
mkdir -p PIC/LedProject
cd PIC/LedProject/
gedit led.c
gcc -Wall -W -Werror led.c -o LedProC
```

and here is my error.please help me to sort this issue

```
In file included from led.c:1:0:
16f877a.h:91:0: error: ignoring #pragma maxram  [-Werror=unknown-pragmas]
16f877a.h:99:0: error: ignoring #pragma memmap INDF_ADDR [-Werror=unknown-pragmas]
16f877a.h:100:0: error: ignoring #pragma memmap TMR0_ADDR [-Werror=unknown-pragmas]
16f877a.h:101:0: error: ignoring #pragma memmap PCL_ADDR [-Werror=unknown-pragmas]
16f877a.h:102:0: error: ignoring #pragma memmap STATUS_ADDR [-Werror=unknown-pragmas]
16f877a.h:103:0: error: ignoring #pragma memmap FSR_ADDR [-Werror=unknown-pragmas]
16f877a.h:104:0: error: ignoring #pragma memmap PORTA_ADDR [-Werror=unknown-pragmas]
16f877a.h:105:0: error: ignoring #pragma memmap PORTB_ADDR [-Werror=unknown-pragmas]
16f877a.h:106:0: error: ignoring #pragma memmap PORTC_ADDR [-Werror=unknown-pragmas]
16f877a.h:107:0: error: ignoring #pragma memmap PORTD_ADDR [-Werror=unknown-pragmas]
16f877a.h:108:0: error: ignoring #pragma memmap PORTE_ADDR [-Werror=unknown-pragmas]
16f877a.h:109:0: error: ignoring #pragma memmap PCLATH_ADDR [-Werror=unknown-pragmas]
16f877a.h:110:0: error: ignoring #pragma memmap INTCON_ADDR [-Werror=unknown-pragmas]
16f877a.h:111:0: error: ignoring #pragma memmap PIR1_ADDR [-Werror=unknown-pragmas]
16f877a.h:112:0: error: ignoring #pragma memmap PIR2_ADDR [-Werror=unknown-pragmas]
16f877a.h:113:0: error: ignoring #pragma memmap TMR1L_ADDR [-Werror=unknown-pragmas]
16f877a.h:114:0: error: ignoring #pragma memmap TMR1H_ADDR [-Werror=unknown-pragmas]
16f877a.h:115:0: error: ignoring #pragma memmap T1CON_ADDR [-Werror=unknown-pragmas]
16f877a.h:116:0: error: ignoring #pragma memmap TMR2_ADDR [-Werror=unknown-pragmas]
16f877a.h:117:0: error: ignoring #pragma memmap T2CON_ADDR [-Werror=unknown-pragmas]
16f877a.h:118:0: error: ignoring #pragma memmap SSPBUF_ADDR [-Werror=unknown-pragmas]
16f877a.h:119:0: error: ignoring #pragma memmap SSPCON_ADDR [-Werror=unknown-pragmas]
16f877a.h:120:0: error: ignoring #pragma memmap CCPR1L_ADDR [-Werror=unknown-pragmas]
16f877a.h:121:0: error: ignoring #pragma memmap CCPR1H_ADDR [-Werror=unknown-pragmas]
16f877a.h:122:0: error: ignoring #pragma memmap CCP1CON_ADDR [-Werror=unknown-pragmas]
16f877a.h:123:0: error: ignoring #pragma memmap RCSTA_ADDR [-Werror=unknown-pragmas]
16f877a.h:124:0: error: ignoring #pragma memmap TXREG_ADDR [-Werror=unknown-pragmas]
16f877a.h:125:0: error: ignoring #pragma memmap RCREG_ADDR [-Werror=unknown-pragmas]
16f877a.h:126:0: error: ignoring #pragma memmap CCPR2L_ADDR [-Werror=unknown-pragmas]
16f877a.h:127:0: error: ignoring #pragma memmap CCPR2H_ADDR [-Werror=unknown-pragmas]
16f877a.h:128:0: error: ignoring #pragma memmap CCP2CON_ADDR [-Werror=unknown-pragmas]
16f877a.h:129:0: error: ignoring #pragma memmap ADRESH_ADDR [-Werror=unknown-pragmas]
16f877a.h:130:0: error: ignoring #pragma memmap ADCON0_ADDR [-Werror=unknown-pragmas]
16f877a.h:131:0: error: ignoring #pragma memmap OPTION_REG_ADDR [-Werror=unknown-pragmas]
16f877a.h:132:0: error: ignoring #pragma memmap TRISA_ADDR [-Werror=unknown-pragmas]
16f877a.h:133:0: error: ignoring #pragma memmap TRISB_ADDR [-Werror=unknown-pragmas]
16f877a.h:134:0: error: ignoring #pragma memmap TRISC_ADDR [-Werror=unknown-pragmas]
16f877a.h:135:0: error: ignoring #pragma memmap TRISD_ADDR [-Werror=unknown-pragmas]
16f877a.h:136:0: error: ignoring #pragma memmap TRISE_ADDR [-Werror=unknown-pragmas]
16f877a.h:137:0: error: ignoring #pragma memmap PIE1_ADDR [-Werror=unknown-pragmas]
16f877a.h:138:0: error: ignoring #pragma memmap PIE2_ADDR [-Werror=unknown-pragmas]
16f877a.h:139:0: error: ignoring #pragma memmap PCON_ADDR [-Werror=unknown-pragmas]
16f877a.h:140:0: error: ignoring #pragma memmap SSPCON2_ADDR [-Werror=unknown-pragmas]
16f877a.h:141:0: error: ignoring #pragma memmap PR2_ADDR [-Werror=unknown-pragmas]
16f877a.h:142:0: error: ignoring #pragma memmap SSPADD_ADDR [-Werror=unknown-pragmas]
16f877a.h:143:0: error: ignoring #pragma memmap SSPSTAT_ADDR [-Werror=unknown-pragmas]
16f877a.h:144:0: error: ignoring #pragma memmap TXSTA_ADDR [-Werror=unknown-pragmas]
16f877a.h:145:0: error: ignoring #pragma memmap SPBRG_ADDR [-Werror=unknown-pragmas]
16f877a.h:146:0: error: ignoring #pragma memmap ADRESL_ADDR [-Werror=unknown-pragmas]
16f877a.h:147:0: error: ignoring #pragma memmap ADCON1_ADDR [-Werror=unknown-pragmas]
16f877a.h:148:0: error: ignoring #pragma memmap EEDATA_ADDR [-Werror=unknown-pragmas]
16f877a.h:149:0: error: ignoring #pragma memmap EEADR_ADDR [-Werror=unknown-pragmas]
16f877a.h:150:0: error: ignoring #pragma memmap EEDATH_ADDR [-Werror=unknown-pragmas]
16f877a.h:151:0: error: ignoring #pragma memmap EEADRH_ADDR [-Werror=unknown-pragmas]
16f877a.h:152:0: error: ignoring #pragma memmap EECON1_ADDR [-Werror=unknown-pragmas]
16f877a.h:153:0: error: ignoring #pragma memmap EECON2_ADDR [-Werror=unknown-pragmas]
16f877a.h:206:1: error: unknown type name ‘data’
16f877a.h:206:9: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before numeric constant
16f877a.h:207:1: error: unknown type name ‘sfr’
16f877a.h:207:9: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before numeric constant
16f877a.h:208:1: error: unknown type name ‘data’
16f877a.h:208:9: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before numeric constant
16f877a.h:209:1: error: unknown type name ‘sfr’
16f877a.h:209:9: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before numeric constant
16f877a.h:267:1: error: unknown type name ‘sbit’
16f877a.h:267:1: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘(’ token
16f877a.h:268:1: error: unknown type name ‘sbit’
16f877a.h:485:1: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘(’ token
16f877a.h:486:1: error: unknown type name ‘sbit’
16f877a.h:486:1: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘(’ token
led.c:2:2: error: invalid preprocessing directive #fuses
led.c:3:2: error: invalid preprocessing directive #use
led.c:4:6: error: return type of ‘main’ is not ‘int’ [-Werror=main]
led.c: In function ‘main’:
led.c:6:3: error: implicit declaration of function ‘output_B’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
led.c:7:3: error: implicit declaration of function ‘delay_us’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
cc1: all warnings being treated as errors
bellvantage@BVPC00024:~/Documents/CCPP/PIC/LedProject$ mkdir -p PIC/LedProject
bellvantage@BVPC00024:~/Documents/CCPP/PIC/LedProject$ cd PIC/LedProject/
bellvantage@BVPC00024:~/Documents/CCPP/PIC/LedProject/PIC/LedProject$ gedit led.c
bellvantage@BVPC00024:~/Documents/CCPP/PIC/LedProject/PIC/LedProject$ gcc -Wall -W -Werror led.c -o LedProC
gcc: error: led.c: No such file or directory
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
```

I refer [this blog](http://embeddedlifehelp.blogspot.com/2010/02/pic-16f877a-help.html) for my circuit

Comment: What exact error message you don't understand? And your source code is incorrect C: `#fuses` is incorrect. BTW, you probably need a cross-compiler (e.g. for your `PIC` microcontroller)

Comment: thanks Basile.
I'm beginner to C and PIC Programming.please advice me to correct it
I refer this blog for my code

http://embeddedlifehelp.blogspot.com/2010/02/pic-16f877a-help.html

Comment: I suggest first to learn programming, e.g. read http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/ ; then learn a bit of C on your Linux. At last, install a PIC cross-compiler.

Comment: Please can u refer that blog and advice me to succeed this.
thanks for the link & i already started to learn C :-)

Comment: Then, first experiment coding some C programs on and for your Linux machine (compile with `gcc -Wall -g`, debug with `gdb` & `valgrind`). Once you are fluent in C (and with Linux) consider installing a cross-compiler for PIC and coding for (and cross-compiling with) it.

Answer (score 0):

You are using source code that is not strictly `C` but an extension that includes many preprocessor commands like

```
#fuses XT, NOWDT, NOPROTECT, NOLVP
#use delay (clock =20000000) //clock 20MHz
```

These are use to configure a PIC processor.  The complier for this `C` like language has a built in understanding of functions like

```
delay_us()
```

The compliant `C` compiler (gcc) you used has no understand of fuse, delay_us , etc. and so declares a host of errors.

If you goal is to program a PIC - which I think it is, using this type of `C`, go to MicroChip, CCS, or elsewhere and get their PIC `C` compiler.

If you goal is to program with your gcc on your UBUNTU machine, do not use code designed for PICs.

BTW: There may exist cross-compilers for PIC that compile on your UBUNTU, but I am not aware.

Search the questions for gcc PIC cross-compiler and you may find it answered.